# How can this UI featute be achieved in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

[image]

I want to achieve this feat in Android.
Now this is a processed screenshot of what I want to realize. Above this layout there is a image and those are buttons.Now my question: is this a gridLayout or there are just buttons on a scrollView?

Comment: GridLayout was introduced in API 14: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: yeah i know, but this isn't what I'm asking..

Comment: then I'm not sure what you're asking. You can do this with either GridLayout or with several LinearLayouts

Comment: GridLayout is scrollable. You don't need to worry about scrolling.

Comment: @Aniruddha are you sure? because I'm trying one right now and I can't get it to work.. what is the xml-parameter? I'm using the gridLayout for supporting API 10 and above

Comment: If those buttons are somehow dynamic in their amount, you could also use  a GridView with a Header for your image above.  You could also usr a TableLayout for your Buttons inside a ScrollView. It depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
<GridLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:columnCount="4"
                    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"

  <Button ...>

  <Button ...>

  <Button ...>

  <Button ...>

  <Button ...>

  ..

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: is gridLayout scrollable in case this app is installed in a smaller screen?

Comment: Not sure, but you can put the GridLayout inside a ScrollLView

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this in both the ways, using grid layout and also using the scroll view but for both cases you have to change the background for the button because Android default button have some padding. If you don't want that space, you need create a custom background for your buttons and remove the padding. also have to change the margins of buttons, this can be achieved by using buttons in a scroll view by keeping all the margins to negative numbers. for example - for two buttons, just set the android:layout_marginRight of the first button to "-8dip" or even more. Than the space between the two buttons will get smaller.